# multithreading reading frames from opencv reducing latency

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

Consider the below script:

```
class VideoCaptureThreading:
    def __init__(self, src=0, width=640, height=480):
        self.src = src
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.src)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
        self.grabbed, self.frame = self.cap.read()
        self.started = False
        self.read_lock = threading.Lock()

    def set(self, var1, var2):
        self.cap.set(var1, var2)

    def start(self):
        if self.started:
            print('[!] Threaded video capturing has already been started.')
            return None
        self.started = True
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        while self.started:
            grabbed, frame = self.cap.read()
            with self.read_lock:
                self.grabbed = grabbed
                self.frame = frame

    def read(self):
        with self.read_lock:
            if isinstance(self.frame,np.ndarray):
                frame = self.frame.copy()
                grabbed = self.grabbed
            else:
                frame=None
                grabbed=False
        return grabbed, frame

    def stop(self):
        self.started = False
        self.thread.join()

    def get(self, prop):
        with self.read_lock:
            prop = self.cap.get(prop)
        return prop

    def __exit__(self, exec_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.cap.release()
```

Suppose in the above script, I want to reduce latency in reading the frames from a videocapture object so here  multithreading is used to read and update the frames from buffer in `read() method`
a copy of the frame is created using `copy()` which I feel might be causing lag but again I am making a guess, any helpful explanations are welcomed.

Comment: You could measure the time required to copy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach makes sure the frame is the latest one in the stream in case the stream publishes faster than reading from the buffer. If there is an observable latency, it is most probably because of heavy publisher encoder options or unsuited listener configuration (e.g. realtime flag not set). Copy has a cost but it does not exceed few milliseconds.